# Getting emails and phone numbers from contact without extending Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the email adresses and phone numbers from a contact. My class doesn't `extend Activity` and now I'm stuck.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for getting email contacts

```
public void getEmailContacts() 
    {
        try 
        {
            String name;

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
             cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

            emailIndex=0;
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
            {
                ArrayList<String> emailNameList=new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> emailPhoneList=new ArrayList<String>();
                while (cur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + id, null, null);
                    while (emails.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        String emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        Log.v(name+"==>", emailAddress);
                        if ((!emailAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&(emailAddress.contains("@"))) 
                        {   
                            emailNameList.add(name);
                            emailPhoneList.add(emailAddress);
                            emailIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                    emails.close();         
                }
```

for getting phone contacts

```
String name;

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
            {   
                ArrayList<String> phoneNameList=new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> PhoneList=new ArrayList<String>();

                while (cur.moveToNext()) 
                {                   
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                    {
                        phoneNameList.add(name);                        
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                        {

                            PhoneList.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
```